# Do you need sudo rights to shutdown on Ubuntu?

Tags: application-development

I am looking to migrate a Snoozer application I originally wrote in windows on AutoIt, which when it comes down to it is a Shutdown Snoozer.

I list faling asleep to a movie or show, but I wake up if my pc runs through the night. So I built an application which notifies you that there is a pending shutdown and you have 10 minutes to snooze this otherwise the PC shuts down. The application allows you to repeat this prompt for X times and on a Y interval.

My question is, in Ubuntu will I need sudo rights to shutdown. If so, how can I prevent the application from continually asking the user to authenticate as sudo in order to shutdown the system properly??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the user need to have sudo rights, but you can use NOPASSWD to skip password authentication anyway.

To allow a user to run specific commands, in this case, the shutdown command, edit the /etc/sudoers file, for example:

```
user ALL=/usr/bin/apt-get,/sbin/shutdown
```

A more detailed version which suits your requirement better (user can shut down using `sudo shutdown -h now` and reboot with `sudo reboot`. Users wishing to power down a system can also use `poweroff` or `halt` without password):

```
user hostname =NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown -h now,/sbin/halt,/sbin/poweroff,/sbin/reboot
```

You can use the following command to show what the user can run will tell us what commands the user can run with sudo:

```
sudo -U user –l
```

Answer (score 0):

A very long time ago, I wrote this for someone with the same question. I have no idea if it still works and can't test right now because I don't want to restart :-).

Here you go:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dbus

def main():
    answer = raw_input("Do you really want to shutdown your computer? (Y/n): ")
    if answer in ('y', 'Y', ''):
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        bus_object = bus.get_object("org.freedesktop.Hal", "/org/freedesktop/Hal/devices/computer")
        bus_object.Shutdown(dbus_interface="org.freedesktop.Hal.Device.SystemPowerManagement")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you Timo, I am still writing the UI and saving the application states. I will definately test it once I am ready.